# Why osgviewer works while osgDB::readImageFile() fails?

Tags: 3d, openscenegraph

I'm new to OpenSceneGraph, and now I met a problem. When trying out a simple skybox program, it gives
`Warning: Could not find plugin to read objects from file "xxx.jpg"` when calling `osgDB::readImageFile()`, and I can only see a white screen;

Then I tried using `osgviewer --image xxx.jpg` in cmd, it works well and I can see the picture displayed on the screen.

What's the possible reason for this and what can I do? Thank you!

Comment: Set this in your terminal `OSG_NOTIFY_LEVEL=DEBUG` to check where your program is looking for the plugins. Another way to quickly check if your program is ok is to copy the `jpg` plugins to the executable's folder.

Comment: Thank you, I solved my problem now and I'll remember your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own problem. The reason is that I mixed up two versions of OpenSceneGraph, one is compiled with VS2012 without JPEG plugin and the other is compiled with VS2010 with JPEG plugin. The OSG compiled with VS2010 will not work under VS2012. Now I've found another OSG compiled with VS2012 with all necessary plugins included and the problem is solved.